# How to prove that $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{na+(b-a)i}>\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{1}{(n+1)a+(b-a)i}$ for any $0<a<b$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

To approximate $\int_{a}^{b} \frac1x \,\mathrm{d}x$, we divide the interval $[a, b]$ into $n$ equal parts, yielding

$$\int_{a}^{b} \frac1x \,\mathrm{d}x\approx \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{na+(b-a)i}.$$

Intuitively, increasing the number of partitions should make the estimation of the integral more accurate, i.e.
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{na+(b-a)i}>\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{1}{(n+1)a+(b-a)i}.$$

Through numerical experiments, I found that this conclusion should be correct. However, I found it challenging to prove this conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conjecture is correct. Generally one can show the following:

> If $f: [a, b] \to \Bbb R$ is convex and nonincreasing then the Riemann sums
> $$
>  S_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f\left(a+(b-a)\frac{k}{n} \right)
> $$
> decrease to the integral:
> $$
> \int_a^b f(x) \, dx  \le S_{n+1} \le S_n 
> $$
> for all positive integers $n$. If $f$ is strictly decreasing and strictly convex then both inequalities are strict.

The first inequality simply follows from the fact that $f$ is decreasing.

Here is a proof of the second inequality. To simplify the notation I'll assume that $a= 0$ and $b=1$. For $1 \le k\le n$ is
$$
 \frac{k-1}{n} < \frac{k}{n+1} < \frac kn
$$
and the convexity condition for these three points gives
$$
 f \left( \frac{k}{n+1} \right)
\le \frac{k}{n+1}f \left( \frac{k-1}{n}\right)
+ \frac{n+1-k}{n+1}f \left( \frac{k}{n}\right) \, .
$$
(Note that the inequality is strict if $f$ is strictly convex.)
It follows that
$$
S_{n+1} 
\le \frac{1}{n+1} f(0)
+ \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n \left[ \frac{k}{n+1}f \left( \frac{k-1}{n}\right)
+ \frac{n+1-k}{n+1}f \left( \frac{k}{n}\right)\right] 
$$
Collecting terms with the same argument of $f$ on the right-hand side gives
$$
S_{n+1} \le \frac{n+2}{(n+1)^2} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)
+ \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} f(1) \, .
$$
Finally,
$$
 f(1) \le \frac 1n \sum_{k=0} ^{n-1} f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)
$$
since $f$ is nonincreasing, and substituting that for $f(1)$ in the previous inequality gives exactly
$$
 S_{n+1} \le S_n \, .
$$

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative and intuitive argument, by $\Delta_n =\frac{b-a}n$ we have

$$S_n = \Delta_n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f\left(a+i\Delta_n \right)=\Delta_n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac12\left[f\left(a+i\Delta_n \right)-f\left(a+(i+1)\Delta_n \right)\right]+$$

$$+\Delta_n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac12\left[f\left(a+i\Delta_n \right)+f\left(a+(i+1)\Delta_n \right)\right]=\Delta_n\frac{f(a)-f(b)}2+T_n$$

since the first sum telescopes and where $T_n$ is the trapezoidal estimation for the integral with $n$ subintervals, and similarly by $\Delta_{n+1} =\frac{b-a}{n+1}$ we have

$$S_{n+1} = \Delta_{n+1}\frac{f(a)-f(b)}2+T_{n+1}$$

therefore, since $\Delta_n>\Delta_{n+1}$ and, is since $f$ is convex and nonincreasing, $T_n>T_{n+1}$ and we have $S_n>S_{n+1}$.

Comment: Why does the left inequality in the second line hold? I am probably missing something simple.

Comment: @MartinR I'm checking indeed maybe not correct!